# How to access log4net appender file value and replace in the azure pipelines

Tags: xml, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to replace log file path from pipeline

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
   <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="appender1">
        <file value="log.txt"/>
    </appender>
   </log4net>
  </applicationSettings>
 </configSections>
</configuration>
```

I am using `FileTransform` task to achieve this.
How to access log4net appender file value and replace in the azure pipelines
What and How should be the "Name" to be set in the variable.
I want the "Value" to be set as "D:\Logs\log.txt". Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your pipeline and your transformation definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is described in the [FileTransform task document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops#arguments). The variables defined in pipeline will be matched against the `key` or `name` entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections.

> Variables defined in the build or release pipelines will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.

So you can add a `name` attribute to the `file` property in your config file. For example in below. I add a name attribute `LogFile`:

```
 <applicationSettings>
   <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="appender1">
        <file name="LogFile" value="log.txt"/>
    </appender>
   </log4net>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Then you can define a variabled named `LogFile` in Variables section of your azure devops pipeline. See below example:

```
variables:
  LogFile: D:\Logs\log.txt

steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    fileType: xml
```

If you donot want to add a `name` attribute to `file` property. You can use Task [Magic Chuncks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) to replace the value of `file` property.

Set the **transformations**: `configuration/configSections/applicationSettings/log4net/appender/file/@value": "D:\Logs\log.txt"`. See below example:

See [here](https://github.com/magic-chunks/magic-chunks-dotnetcore/wiki/XML) about how to transform XML files

```
steps:
- task: sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks.magic.chunks.MagicChunks@2
  displayName: 'Config transform'
  inputs:
    sourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/path/to/app.config'
    transformations: |
     {
       "configuration/configSections/applicationSettings/log4net/appender/file/@value": "D:\Logs\log.txt"
      }
```